# One word that expresses premature celebrations only to find out that the result is negative

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context

Looking for one word that expresses the following:

> Don't sell the skin till you have caught the bear.
>   Never sell the bear's skin before one has killed the beast.

Comment: Try ***d’oh***!

Comment: In AmE, a common way of expressing this would be "Don't count your chickens before they hatch", but I have nothing in a single word.

Comment: This is used in BrE as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Anticipointment](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anticipointment)

From Wiktionary:
Etymology: Blend of anticipation +‎ disappointment

Noun (uncountable)
(rare) The state of mind resulting from excitedly anticipating a strongly promoted product, event, film, etc, and then being disappointed when it fails to meet the expectations generated by this promotion.

> The unparalleled media hype surrounding the new film guaranteed that fans would experience **anticipointment**.

Anecdotally, it does seem to be gaining traction with Australian sport fans. Many supporters are excited before a game, only to experience *anticipointment* when they realise their team can no longer win.

Comment: Thank you for linking to a definition. Now please also (2) explicitly state the source of the definition (Wiktionary), and (3) *quote* the definition.